# How to disable @flow rule

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I have a very annoying flow glitch:

```
flow disable Cannot use `Component` [1] with less than 1 type argument.
```

I guess it happens cuz flow requires proptypes annotation.
Some my components dont have any additional props. And I dont want to put just empty props descriptor into my components.
How I can solve this?
Maybe I understand it wrong.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
type Props = {};
class SomeComponent extends Component<Props> {...
```

Comment: What about `class SomeComponent extends Component<void> {`

Comment: I don't want to modify this. Cuz it will affect plenty files without reason

Comment: I guess that's it: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5869